# SonarQube 6.7 (LTS) issue in disabling rules in a quality profile and delay in authentication process

Tags: java, ldap, sonarqube, delay

I have downloaded [SonarQube 6.7 LTS](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) and installed on both Windows 10 and centOs 7. On both machines I have problem in following:

1- Problem in enabling/disabling rules in quality profile. While in the 'Rule Page with comments and examples about that rule and clicking on enable/disable in a quality profile it says Still Working and nothing happens. ( By refreshing the page you can see that the action is done).

I found this error in firefox console while disabling a rule:

> TypeError : this.options.app.controller.getRuleDetails(...).done is not a function

[Image Of Page with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Egj.png)

2- Delay in authentication while connected to Ldap. Local users can login without any problem but ldap users sometimes have about 1 min delay in login and sometimes logs in with out any problem.

In addition there is no error in any of log files! I have not changed any default configuartion and just added Ldap part. Both machines have 4GB of Memory and 4x Core of cpu. I tested it with Firefox 57 and chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open a new Stackoverflow question for each question you want to ask. I suggest to remove the paragraph about ldap here, and put it into separate Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the confirmation of the front-end developer, that fixed https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10054 . He confirmed, that the issues about enabling and disabling of rules you described will be resolved in SonarQube 7.0 and 6.7.1.

Comment: what about delay in authentication using Active Directory. I used old ldap plugin and the problem did not solved. After upgrading to sonar qube 6.7 I have this delay in authentication for active directory users. I have tested lastest ldap and active directory plugin but still have problem.

Comment: @malekmali Please open a new question for this topic. Having two, separate questions will it make easier for future readers of your questions and the related answers.